# Telling gcc to fail to compile when in pre-C99 mode

Tags: c, gcc

I am giving a lecture on the history of C, and would like to show some idioms that used to be impossible but now are (in particular, defining variables in the middle of the block). I would like to show that older C compilers wouldn't compile it.

`gcc` has the `-std=` option for setting the language standard. Unfortunately, setting it for `-std=c89` does not produce compilation errors on defining variables in the middle of a block.

I was hoping for a more accurate std version (i.e. - `-std=knr`), but I could not find any such option.

Am I missing something? Is this a bug in GCC?

```
gcc (Ubuntu 8.2.0-7ubuntu1) 8.2.0
```

The code that erroneously compiles:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(argc, argv)
int argc;
char *argv[];
{
        printf("Hello, world\n");

        int a;

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Any reason this is not an answer?

Comment: Why are you using such a modern system as Ubuntu 8?  Shouldn't you be using something older?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler not if it works. I'm not trying to emulate the olden days (not that there is much way to do it), just demonstrate how things were.

Answer (score 5):

If you want truly strict conformance to a `-std` flag, it should be accompanied by the `-pedantic-errors` flag.

As a demonstration, your code on [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/T7tXMpzHHrOcRThj) with those flags produces:

```
prog.c: In function 'main':
prog.c:9:9: error: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
         int a;
         ^~~
```

Comment: Although, as the diagnostic text indicates, GCC is aware of what you are trying to do. It's probably not as authentic a diagnostic as the one that a compiler truly predating C99 will produce.